# How to categorize text data based on a value in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, printing

I am using Excel to generate a list of people working in the company containing information about the employees relevant for our department.

The spreadsheet looks generally like this (fictive data):

```
Name        Department        Function        Telephone       E-mail
J. Juggler  Sales             Fixer           4493            jj@company.com
A. Zen      Front Office      Elevator boy    1363            az@company.com
etc....
```

On screen the list works great. We can filter by department or function and just do general <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> searches.
However, my manager has asked me to make a print friendly version so he can print and hang the list at certain locations.

The desired printed format would be something like this:

```
Front Office
    A. Zen      Front Office      Elevator boy    1363            az@company.com
    ....        ....              ....            ....            ....
Sales
    J. Juggler  Sales             Fixer           4493            jj@company.com
    ....        ....              ....            ....            ....
```

I tried using a pivot table for this. It went OK until I tried to add the contact details as values. It then gave me the sum(?) of the value in the cell instead of simply the value.

So how do I categorize such a spreadsheet to achieve the described format? The spreadsheet contains about 150 rows and 8 departments.

Answer (score 1):

If you first sort the data by the "Department" column, you can select all the data and use "Subtotals" in the Data Ribbon to insert a header before each department as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only thing that you need to do to get your pivot table to work is to change the datatype on your telephone column from number (or general) to string.  This is also a good trick for preserving leading zeros in things like zipcodes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it to no avail. The problem remains that I can only set "Summarize by" to "Count", "Sum", "Min", "Max", etc. regardless of cell format.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the spreadsheet by column B (Department), the rows will be re-ordered so all people in the same department are listed together. That will give you your desired print format. The only other thing you may want to do is to insert header rows with the department names.

If I start with this:
[image: Unsorted]

I get this after sorting by Department:
[image: sorted]

You can also add a secondary sort, so the names are alphabetical within the department, but to make that work the initials would need to be in a separate column, like here:
[image: Initials separated]

Extracting the initial can easily be done with the Text-to-Columns function, if you select "delimited" with " " (space) as the delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The sorting is not the problem. It's the adding of header rows that I'm trying to automate.

Comment: The header rows could be inserted with a macro that searches for a change in the value of the Department, and inserts a line with the department name before it. Very simple to a good programmer, but would probably take me a day to figure it out. And, this computer is et to block access to macros.